# Age detection for Affectiva SDK

Tags: android, affdex-sdk

I've used Affectiva SDK for Android.
It can do face detection as well emotions.
I wanted to age detection for a specific usecase.

Can Affectiva Android SDK provide age detection ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for example:

```
detector = new FrameDetector(context);
detector.setDetectAge(true);
detector.setImageListener(new Detector.ImageListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageResults(List<Face> faceList, Frame frame, float timeStamp) {
        for (Face face : faceList) {
            Log.i("demo", "age for face ID " + face.getId() + " is " + face.appearance.getAge());
        }
    }
});
```

See the open source FrameDetectorDemo sample app at https://github.com/Affectiva/android-sdk-samples for a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation does say it provides age detection as well.

Jul 2016

Windows/Linux/Android SDK 3.1

Improved emotion metrics. The valence includes new expressions in its calculation.
Added models for classifying ethnicity and estimating age range.

Comment: Yes, the android SDK includes models for age estimation. I don't understand your question..